# Dart Flutter Future Void _CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<String?>' in type cast) Error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have such a code. But I am getting error.

[image]

```
   _CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<String?>' in type cast)
```

Codes:

```
Future<List<String?>> listUpload() async {
        final prefences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        final getTests = prefences.getStringList("tests"); // get item
        return Future.value(getTests);
      }
```

---

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `listUpload` can possibly return `Null` depending on the situation. But you have specified a return type of `Future<List<String?>>`.
To make it work try a return type `dynamic` (not preferred) or check for `null`  before returning a value.

```
dynamic listUpload() async {
        final prefences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        final getTests = prefences.getStringList("tests"); // get item
        return Future.value(getTests);
      }
```